# Alignment issue with longtabu

Tags: tables, longtable, tabu

I'm using `longtabu` to create a table.

This is the code:

```
{\footnotesize 
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {|l|c|c|l|l|c|c|c|c|}

\hline
\textbf{Frame} &
\textbf{Cam} &
\textbf{ID} &
\textbf{Class} &
\textbf{State} &
\textbf{Type} &
\textbf{Time} &
\textbf{Info ID (2)} &
\textbf{Info ID (4)} 
\\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\endhead

\endfoot

\endlastfoot

403 & 2 & O@61 & Pers. & Not assoc. & None & 0 & A@201 & B@NA \\ \hline

\end{longtabu}
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: result longtabu]

How can I fix the mismatch between rows?

Comment: Compile again; `longtable` requires up to four runs of LaTeX in order to get columns with equal widths across pages. It issues a warning when a new run is required.

Comment: note you are not using any tabu features there you could use `longtable` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile again: `longtable` (and so also `longtabu` that's based over it) requires up to four (rarely more) runs to stabilize: at each pass it writes the column widths to the `.aux` file for the next run. Most of the times a couple of runs are sufficient, but in some cases more are needed. In any case, if the widths are changed from the previous run, a warning is emitted on the terminal and in the log file:

```
Package longtable Warning: Table widths have changed. Rerun LaTeX.
```

Software such as `latexmk` knows about this warning and will launch another run if needed.